# subprocess calling blast does not return all output

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, blast

I'm using subprocess Popen to call a blastn query.

```
    cmd_list = ['blastn','-db', sequences_db, '-query','temp_query.fasta','-outfmt','6']
    print(cmd_list)
    blast_process = Popen(cmd_list, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    return_code = blast_process.wait()
    if return_code != 0:
        raise IOError("Blast Error!")
    err = blast_process.stderr.read()
    out = blast_process.stdout.read()
    print(out)
    print(err)
    return out
```

Running the same blastn command in the shell does return an output.

If I use -outfmt 6, it returns nothing, if I remove that parameter, I got only the first part of the ouptut:

```
A.fsa -query temp_query.fasta
BLASTN 2.2.28+


Reference: Zheng Zhang, Scott Schwartz, Lukas Wagner, and Webb
Miller (2000), "A greedy algorithm for aligning DNA sequences", J
Comput Biol 2000; 7(1-2):203-14.



Database: data/sequences/iwgsc_refseqv1.0_chr1A.fsa
           1 sequences; 594,102,056 total letters

...
```

But the results are missing. Again, if I run this command on the shell, I got the full output.

So there's something like if my code does not wait until blast finish executing.

Running from the shell, same dir as the python script:

```
 blastn -db data/sequences/db/iwgsc_refseqv1.0_chr1A.fsa -query temp_query.fasta -outfmt 6
KR082534_1      chr1A   99.93   1400    1       0       1       1400    591615416       591614017        0.0     2580
```

Also, using an outfile from blast writes nothing in it when running from python, and the correct output from the shell

Comment: Is stuff going to stderr instead?

Comment: Assembling a string and then `split()`ing it is going to be error-prone. Is there a reason you aren't assembling a list in the first place?

Comment: not at all, however double check, the list is ok

Comment: @MadPhysicist nope, it's empty

Comment: This code is going to deadlock if output is very long at all, because `blastn` can't write output if the parent process isn't `read`ing from its end of the pipe. So if you wait for the program to exit before you read its output, it can never do a write (past the pipe buffer limit, which is typically somewhere between 4kb-64kb depending on the version of Linux in use), so it never gets to where it can exit. (So I actually disbelieve that this code works at all, unless `blastn` is itself *not actually writing any output*).

Comment: Use `subprocess.communicate()` to avoid what I described above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've tried with communicate, but it returns ('', '') empty stdout and stderr

Comment: Then your `blastn` program is emitting no output. That's not Python's business.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just added the shell output

Comment: The shell output doesn't mean anything. For all I know it only writes to TTYs and not FIFOs.

Comment: ok that's interesting, what I could do is to write to a file. You could elaborate a very good answer by being polite

Comment: ...that said, it might be helpful to log both `repr(cmd_list)` and the shell log when run with `bash -x`, just to be sure there aren't any surprising differences between the two. And you could try piping the shell output with `| cat` and see if that changes behavior -- if so, that would prove the TTY point.

Comment: strangely, the output file (-out filename) from blast is empty when running from subprocess. There's something else there.

Comment: *shrug*. If I were debugging this on a machine I controlled, I'd pull out [Sysdig](http://sysdig.org/) and look at what the `blastn` program is actually doing when invoked each way. But without knowing that program, how it's written, how it interacts with its environment, etc etc etc., any speculation I continued to do here would be just that -- speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to try this?

```
cmd_list = ['blastn','-db', sequences_db, '-query','temp_query.fasta','-outfmt','6']
blast_process = Popen(cmd_list, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
if return_code != 0:
    raise IOError("Blast Error!")
else:
    out = blast_process.stdout.read()
    for line in iter(out, b''):
        print line.strip()
```